# how to return value from tryAdvance method in Java8's spliterator?

Tags: java-8, java-stream

I am new to Java 8 and trying to understand the splitIterator feature of java8.

I have written below code, my requirement is whenever I call get(); the get method should return me one value from itr3; Is it possible to get the same? and how?

```
public class TestSplitIterator {

static List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

public static void main(String args[]) {

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        list.add(i);
    }
    // below method call should return only one value whenever i call it;
    get(list);
}

private static int get(List<Integer> list) {
    Collections.sort(list, Collections.reverseOrder());

    System.out.println(list);

    Spliterator<Integer> itr1 = list.spliterator();
    Spliterator<Integer> itr2 = itr1.trySplit();
    Spliterator<Integer> itr3 = itr2.trySplit();
    // i want to return value from itr3 whenever get(List list ic called)

  }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I don't misunderstand you. you need a **collector** object that collect the elements in a spliterator. for example:

```
Integer[] collector = new Integer[1];

boolean exist = itr3.tryAdvance(value -> collector[0] = value);

System.out.println(collector[0]);
```

**OR** collect all of the elements in a spliterator by using another `List`, for example:

```
List<Integer> collector = new ArrayList<>();

while (itr3.tryAdvance(collector::add)) ;

System.out.println(collector);
```

Comment: Instead of `while (itr3.tryAdvance(collector::add)) ;` you can use `itr3.forEachRemaining(collector::add);` which will do exactly the same (`default` implementation) or semantically the same in a potentially more efficient way (if overridden by the specific `Spliterator`).

Comment: I've seen that for this task of collecting one element from a spliterator, some people use a `Holder` class that implements `Consumer`: `class HoldingConsumer<T> implements Consumer<T> { private T t; public void accept(T t) { this.t = t; } public T get() { return t; } }`

Comment: @Holger, using forEachRemaining would have been useful if one want to traverse through the list, my requirement was to fetch single value every time i call get method. can same be achieved by using (collector::add)?

Comment: @Rogger296: I was referring to the second example of this answer, which calls `tryAdvance` in a loop until it returns `false`. That loop is equivalent to `forEachRemaining`, which will copy all remaining elements. Of course, you can call the `tryAdvance` method without a loop, i.e. `itr3.tryAdvance(collector::add);` to add only a single element to the list.

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner thanks you share the code. could you say the benefit of your code?

Comment: @holi-java no particular benefit, just a matter of style